# What type of security should I use if I wish to have a Forgotton Password ability on our website? AES?

Tags: .net, security, passwords, forgot-password, password-recovery

unfortunately, we've been requested to offer our users the ability to get an email sent to their registered account, their password .. if they have forgotten their password.

"Click here if you have forgotten your password"

So - this means i need to be able to DECRYPT the password. I don't like it, but that's the requirements. I'm used to use a SALT and HASHING a password with SHA1. then storing the salt and the hashed password into the repository.

Not sure what I should be doing if I wish to store the password which can be decrypted now. Is it more or less the same, but I should use AES instead?

Would love some help (and preferably code samples in .NET).

Cheers!

NOTE: Please don't turn this thread into a topic about HASHING vs DECRYPTING vs OpenAuth.

Comment: This is, of course, [a very, very, very bad idea](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/257.html) (and you apparently realize this). The right way to do it is to provide a temporary password or a "one-time-only reset password" link. Have you tried convincing your client to reconsider this? Providing a way to recover passwords is considered a weakness, not a feature.

Comment: Preferred method is to generate a password and send that to the registered email address. No decrypt needed. User would be require to set the password again on next login.

Comment: Preferred methods or not, I can't tell my client what to do (even though I've suggested strongly against this). :(

Comment: I have to say I disagree. I've made the case that I'm being paid for my experience and expertise, and given users something completely usable (such as the alternate methods suggested) without compromising the application - or my reputation. Granted, it's much easier from me because I have standards to meet (HIPAA). Are you sure there isn't some kind of security requirements doc out there that you can fall back on?

Comment: @overslacked - unfortunately user experience is more important than security for this project (not my call). Which is why I want to avoid a debate about hashing (which is what i always do with reset password) vs decrypting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

1. Change the user's password temporarily and email the user the new password, which he is required to change in the next login.
2. Have a functionality to reset the password instead. It is quite similar to the first option, but instead you need to create a temporary token and send that to the user as a link.
3. If you really, really need to encrypt the password and send it to the user over plaintext, then you need to find a good encryption scheme to protect the passwords while they're in the database. You can simply create a random key or a derived key using [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) and then you can use AES combined with [HMAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmac.aspx) (for verification) to encrypt and store the password. Your application needs to be aware of this key to be able to decrypt the data, which is a security risk. Possibly you can store this key in the web.config file or something similar which should never be accessible from the outside and protect it using [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.dpapiprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx) or the [RSAKeyContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede.aspx).

If you go with option 1 or 2, you don't need to be able to decrypt the password, so you can use a hash + salt, which will be the most secure method.

Comment: And I can't stress enough how ***really*** ***really*** ***really*** ***really*** ***really*** ***really*** ***really*** ***BAD*** option 3 is.

Comment: @software monkey - agreed. can't agree more .. but .. it's not for me to decide! i've done my part .. now I need to do my job. Please don't say my job is to NOT do that ... there's what _I_ would do and what i'm paid to do, regardless of my opinions. (and don't say get a new job).

Comment: @Pure.Krome , I know how that feels. In this case go for option 3. It is still a reasonably secure scheme. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Actually, I would argue that as the domain "expert" here, convincing the DFU that option 3 is not an option is precisely your job - do we really need another TJ-MAX, etc, on the internet?  That said, best of luck.

Comment: 1 is a terrible option too. You shouldn't be able to arbitrarily reset someone else's password. (You also need to use a decent random number generator for options 1 and 2...)

Comment: @tc, yes true. should probably have a security question before you can create a new password.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that password will be traveling unencrypted over internet, high security encryption may event not be that relevant. But in any case AES should be sufficient.

Still want to ask - was there an option on the table to allow users to reset passwords rather than receive them via e-mail?